# Script for Build and Clean /Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, automation, filewriter, datareader

i need some help, i am doing some benchmarks with some compilers in Eclipse and i have to Build and Clean several times, can anyone help me how to write a script that will do that automatic. The compiler displays in the Eclipse Console the Build time which i need.

Thank you for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an ant task and make run it on worspace startup. In the ant task you can use eclipse built in ant tasks like workspacebuild etc..